# python suds Error in XML

Tags: python, soap, suds

i tryied for a couple of hours to receive data from an Soap Webservice.

This is my Code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault

WSDL_URL = 'gatewaywebservice.asmx?wsdl'
client = Client(WSDL_URL)

checkIfExists = client.factory.create('checkIfExists')
checkIfExists.SessionID = ''
checkIfExists.UserID = 'ttester@email.com'
try:
   response = client.service.CustomerService(checkIfExists)
   #print response
   if response.Error:
      print response.Error
   else:
      pass
except WebFault, e:
  print e
print client.last_sent()
print client.last_received()
```

This is what i sent:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="asdf"                                                xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:CustomerService>
         <ns0:CustomerService>
            <ns0:SessionID></ns0:SessionID>
            <ns0:UserID>ttester@email.com</ns0:UserID>
         </ns0:CustomerService>
      </ns0:CustomerService>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and this is what the Webserver expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GATEWAY xmlns="urn:Software-com:Gateway:v7-00">
<CustomerService>
    <checkIfExists>
        <SessionID/>
        <UserID>test</UserID>
    </checkIfExists>
</CustomerService>
</GATEWAY>
```

How can I update my code to send an valid request?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example of what the webserver expects is certainly not a valid SOAP request; SUDS can only send what the WSDL specifies; if what SUDS produces is wrong, then the server sent you incorrect WSDL.

Comment: IIRC, do a `print client` after you initialized the client on the url, and **it will display the interface** that suds is proposing to you for the web service. It maybe slightly different from what you think. I remember I had to to that for it to work correctly once: suds awaited two leaf objects only, where I was giving as input an object containing the two leaf objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Suds plugin to modify the XML before it is sent.

In the example below the `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` tag is modified to match the webserver expectations:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        envelope = context.envelope
        envelope.name = 'GATEWAY'
        envelope.setPrefix(None)
        envelope.nsprefixes = {'xmlns' : 'urn:Software-com:Gateway:v7-00'}
        # and so on...
        # envelope[0] is the Header tag, envelope[1] the Body tag
        # you can use "print context.envelope" to view the modified XML

client = Client(WSDL_URL, plugins=[MyPlugin()])
```

You have to complete the `marshalled` method to fully transform the XML. But before doing that, check if you have the correct WSDL file, as @Martijn Pieters says.